# Is there an alternative for Sling JsonItemWriter in the Jackson library

Tags: java, aem, jackson-databind

I am looking for the best alternative to get a dump of json from a given jcr node.

Old code uses the deprecated sling.commons.json library.

```
Node node = session.getNode(“/content/pathToPage/mypage”);
StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
JsonItemWriter jsonWriter = new JsonItemWriter(null);
jsonWriter.dump(node, stringWriter, -1, true);
```

Since  org.apache.sling.commons.json.jcr.JsonItemWriter is deprecated , is there an alternative in the jackson library to get the json data for a given JCR node ?

I tried creating a valuemap of the given resource only reaches the first level of the resource and does not retrieve the children .

```
ValueMap valueMap = resource.getValueMap();
```

Comment: Did you try [TidyJsonItemWriter](https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/6-3/sites/developing/using/reference-materials/javadoc/com/day/cq/commons/TidyJsonItemWriter.html) which isn't deprecated and extends the `JsonItemWriter` that you mentioned?

Comment: Thanks for the response, yes I tried using TidyJsonItemWriter which works perfectly fine, but as it extends the deprecated JsonItemWriter, I wasn't sure if I should use it and if there was a different alternative.

Comment: Given that `TidyJsonItemWritem` isn't deprecated, I doubt that it would be removed without notice. However, given that the functionality you are expecting of converting the nodes properties to a JSON is very sling specific, there may not be a relevant class / method in jackson to handle the functionality by default, unless there is a sling version of jackson.

Comment: If all you need is a JSON dump, just calling the given resource with the JSON selector will give you that dump. If deprecated, newer AEM versions will just use the new code to generate it. If you need to generate them programmatically, then you can create your custom servlet and produce a JSON output using Jackson or Gson reading the desired properties and children, or use the sling model exporter.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Model Exporter API to transform resources to JSON

```java
@Component(service = MyService.class)
public class MyService {
  
  @Reference
  private ModelExporter modelExporter;
  
  public String getJsonFromResource() {
    final Resource resource = ...;
    
    return modelExporter.export(resource, String.class, new HashMap<>());
  }

}
```

Here's the docs: https://sling.apache.org/apidocs/sling10/org/apache/sling/models/export/spi/ModelExporter.html